# Why does my shader work for BoxGeometry but not my custom BufferGeometry in ThreeJs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader

I have an issue where I have a shader that draws white borders around the edges of geometry of a mesh (borrowed & modified from @prisoner849, refer to his jsfiddle here (https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/kmau6591/) ).

I have it working with one type of geometry (`BoxGeometry`) but not `BufferGeometry` which is what I want it to work on since I need to do custom manipulation of the vertices.  I created a JSFiddle to demonstrate where you can see the shader working on the box created via ( `new BoxGeometry` ) and the other was created using `BufferGeometry` and setting attributes manually.

I suspect I must be not setting the attributes correctly, but I am not sure what to do as I can't find any information about how to setup the `BufferGeometry` correctly.

Attached below is my JSFiddle demonstrating the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/gentleman_goat66/o5wn3bpf/135/

The lines of code of interest are below:

**Working Box Code:**

```
const geometryBox = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    const sample_box = new THREE.Mesh(geometryBox, shader_material);
    sample_box.scale.y = 3;
    this.heatmap.add(sample_box);
```

[image]

**My Custom Box Code (Not Working!)**

```
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    const vertices = [
      -2, 0, 1,//0, floor, bottom left
      -1, 0, 1,//1, floor, bottom right
      -1, 0, -1,//2, floor, top right
      -2, 0, -1,//3 floor, top left
      -2, 3, 1,//4 roof, bottom left
      -1, 3, 1,//5 roof, bottom right
      -1, 3, -1,//6 roof, top right
      -2, 3, -1//7 roof, top left
    ];
    const indices = [
      0, 1, 2,//floor, first triangle
      2, 3, 0,//floor, second triangle
      4, 5, 6,//roof, first triangle
      6, 7, 4,//roof, second triangle
      3, 0, 4,//west wall, first triangle
      3, 4, 7,//west wall, second triangle
      0, 1, 5,//south wall, first triangle
      0, 5, 4,//south wall, first triangle
      1, 2, 6,//east wall, first triangle
      1, 6, 5,//east wall, second triangle
      2, 3, 7,//north wall, first triangle
      2, 7, 6,//north wall, second triangle
    ];
    const colors = [
      2,0,0, // bottom left
      0,2,0, // bottom right
      0,2,0, // top right
      2,0,0,  // top left
      2,0,0, // bottom left
      0,2,0, // bottom right
      0,2,0, // top right
      2,0,0  // top left
    ];
    geometry.setIndex(indices);
    geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
    geometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({side:THREE.FrontSide,vertexColors:true,color: 0xFFFFFF });
    var shader_material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
      vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
      fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
      uniforms: {
        thickness: {
          value: 1.5
        }
      }
    });
    const sample_rectangle = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, shader_material);
    this.heatmap.add(sample_rectangle);
```

[image]

**HTML**

```
<script type="importmap">
{
"imports": 
  {
    "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.151.3/build/three.module.js",
    "OrbitControls": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.151.3/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
  }
}
</script>
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

            #include <common>
      #include <uv_pars_vertex>
      #include <displacementmap_pars_vertex>
      #include <color_pars_vertex>
      #include <fog_pars_vertex>
      #include <morphtarget_pars_vertex>
      #include <skinning_pars_vertex>
      #include <shadowmap_pars_vertex>
      #include <specularmap_pars_fragment>
      #include <logdepthbuf_pars_vertex>
      #include <clipping_planes_pars_vertex>
      
            varying vec2 vUv;
      
            void main() {
            
                #include <beginnormal_vertex>
                #include <morphnormal_vertex>
                #include <begin_vertex>
                #include <morphtarget_vertex>
                
        vUv = uv;
        
                //gl_Position = vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);

            }

</script>
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
            varying vec2 vUv;
        uniform float thickness;
      
      float edgeFactor(vec2 p){
        vec2 grid = abs(fract(p - 0.5) - 0.5) / fwidth(p) / thickness;
        return min(grid.x, grid.y);
        }
      
            void main() {

                float a = edgeFactor(vUv);
      
        vec3 c = mix(vec3(1), vec3(0), a);
      
        gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.0);

            }

</script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'OrbitControls';

class Heatmap {
  constructor(){
    console.log("Heatmap - constructor()");
    
    //ThreeJS Variables
    this.camera = null;
    this.scene = null;
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    this.orbital_controls = null;
    this.ambientLight = null;
    this.heatmap = new THREE.Object3D(); //This will hold all the meshes that make up the heatmap
    
    //Animation Related Variables
    this.clock = new THREE.Clock();
    this.delta = 0;
    this.fps = 60; //60 fps
        this.interval = 1/this.fps;
        this.seconds = 2; //seconds for animation
        this.timeSoFar = 0;
        this.targetTime = 3;
    
    //Setup
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.setUpCamera();
    this.setUpRenderer();
    this.setUpLighting();
    this.setUpOrbitalControls();
    
    //Add optional GridHelper for Debug
    this.scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper());
    
    //TODO: Create the heatmap here
    this.createDataRectangle();
    
    //Add the finished heatmap to the scene
    this.scene.add(this.heatmap);
    this.render();
    this.animate();
  }
  setUpRenderer(){
    console.log("Heatmap - setUpRenderer()");
    let width = $('#container').width();
    let height = $('#container').height();
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(width,height);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
 
    $("#container").html(this.renderer.domElement);
    
    window.addEventListener("resize", event => {
      this.camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      this.renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
    });
  }
  setUpCamera(){
    console.log("Heatmap - setUpCamera()");
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 100);
    this.camera.position.z = 4;
  }
  setUpLighting(){
    console.log("Heatmap - setUpLighting()");
    this.ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
    this.scene.add(this.ambientLight);
  }
  setUpOrbitalControls(){
    console.log("Heatmap - setUpOrbitalControls()");
    this.orbital_controls = new OrbitControls( this.camera, this.renderer.domElement );
    this.orbital_controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    this.orbital_controls.enableDamping = true;
    this.orbital_controls.dampingFactor = 0.025;
    this.orbital_controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI/2.0;
    this.orbital_controls.minDistance = 2.0;
    this.orbital_controls.maxDistance = 80.0;
    this.orbital_controls.update();
    
    this.orbital_controls.addEventListener( 'change', function(){
      if (this.target.y < 0){
          this.target.y = 0;
          /* camera.position.y = -1; */
      } else if (this.target.y > 1){
          this.target.y = 1;
          /* camera.position.y = 1; */
      }
    });
  }
  createDataRectangle(){ //TODO: Make this create at a position specified
    console.log("Heatmap - createDataRectangle()");
    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    const vertices = [
      -2, 0, 1,//0, floor, bottom left
      -1, 0, 1,//1, floor, bottom right
      -1, 0, -1,//2, floor, top right
      -2, 0, -1,//3 floor, top left
      -2, 3, 1,//4 roof, bottom left
      -1, 3, 1,//5 roof, bottom right
      -1, 3, -1,//6 roof, top right
      -2, 3, -1//7 roof, top left
    ];
    const indices = [
      0, 1, 2,//floor, first triangle
      2, 3, 0,//floor, second triangle
      4, 5, 6,//roof, first triangle
      6, 7, 4,//roof, second triangle
      3, 0, 4,//west wall, first triangle
      3, 4, 7,//west wall, second triangle
      0, 1, 5,//south wall, first triangle
      0, 5, 4,//south wall, first triangle
      1, 2, 6,//east wall, first triangle
      1, 6, 5,//east wall, second triangle
      2, 3, 7,//north wall, first triangle
      2, 7, 6,//north wall, second triangle
    ];
    const colors = [
      2,0,0, // bottom left
      0,2,0, // bottom right
      0,2,0, // top right
      2,0,0,  // top left
      2,0,0, // bottom left
      0,2,0, // bottom right
      0,2,0, // top right
      2,0,0  // top left
    ];
    geometry.setIndex(indices);
    geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
    geometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({side:THREE.FrontSide,vertexColors:true,color: 0xFFFFFF });
    var shader_material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
      vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
      fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
      uniforms: {
        thickness: {
          value: 1.5
        }
      }
    });
    const sample_rectangle = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, shader_material);
    this.heatmap.add(sample_rectangle);
    
    //Demo showing that the same shader material works on a box geometry!
    const geometryBox = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    const sample_box = new THREE.Mesh(geometryBox, shader_material);
    sample_box.scale.y = 3;
    this.heatmap.add(sample_box);
  }
  animate(){
  
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.animate()
    });

    this.orbital_controls.update();//Required for Damping on OrbitControls

    this.delta += this.clock.getDelta();

    if (this.delta  > this.interval) {
      //this.timeSoFar = this.timeSoFar + (1 * morphDirection);

      this.render();
      this.delta = this.delta % this.interval;
    }
  }
  render(){
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("DOM ready!");
  new Heatmap();
});
```

**CSS**

```
body,html{
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

I have an updated fiddle here (https://jsfiddle.net/gentleman_goat66/o5wn3bpf/180/)

So as suggested from a comment UV was the reason it was not working, and while what I have 'looks' like it works when viewing from the bottom angle it does not look the same as the other cube, so it's still not perfect.  Why is this happening?

UPDATE2:

Further messing with random values for the UV seems to change it but there appears to be no rhyme or reason I can detect.  How do you set the UV's correctly for custom buffer geometry, or in this case something simple like my cube made of triangles?

```
var quad_uvs = [
      0, 0,
      1, 0,
      1, 1,
      0, 1,
      0, 0,
      1, 0,
      1, 1,
      0, 1
    ];
```

[image]

UPDATE 3:

After messing with the quads this seems to produce the correct results, but I was literally guessing when I did this, I have no idea why this makes it look correct and the other values did not?

```
var quad_uvs = [
        0, 1,
      0, 0,
      1, 0,
      1, 1,
      0, 0,
      1, 0,
      1, 1,
      0, 1
    ];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gentleman_goat66/o5wn3bpf/184/

[image]

Comment: Your custom geometry is missing uvs.

Comment: Yes you are correct, how do I add these?

Comment: I tried adding these and I can get the shader to 'kind of work', but it doesn't look correct.  How do I create UV map correctly for my shape?

Comment: @Marquizzo I updated my question at the end, any idea how to set the UV correctly to make them match? (Or any pointers on this)

Comment: To start, the bottom faces appear to have incorrect _winding order_. Make sure that is correct, then set the UVs to match. BTW, a related example:  https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_wireframe.html.

Comment: @WestLangley wireframe in that example renders the complete wireframe where as in my example it does a partial.  Can that example do partial wireframes or only full? This is my latest example by the way (https://jsfiddle.net/ZQVerse/b3o5zktr/3/), I was able to get this working but I still have no idea if I set the UV's correctly how what I did worked and why.  Any help on this is appreciated!

Comment: Use a standard material and assign a `map` property and you can see if the uvs are correct. But first fix your winding order.